# How to get data from ManyToManyField - Django

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I have a problem with retrieving data from this ManyToManyField (users) of a model Event:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=26)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="users", blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/',
        default='images/default.png'
    )
```

***users = models.ManyToManyField*** creates an additional table *"events_event_users"*, It stores *user_id* and *event_id* fields. So I want to output all event information from *Event* model, where *user_id* from that additional table is equal to request.user. Please help, how should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `request.user.users.all()`

Note, this is unnecessarily confusing because of the related_name you've set, which defines the backwards relation from User to Event. Leave that out, and the code is more comprehensible:

```
request.user.event_set.all()
```

(If you must set one, at least call it `events`, not `users`.)

Comment: don't know how you expand `request.user` since op didn't provide info about request.user

Comment: Why would OP need to provide any information? `request.user` is provided by Django; even if they substituted their own model, that makes no difference to the fact that we are interested in the *reverse* relation, which is defined on Event.

Comment: What is the content of the intermediate table? Do the events have different user_ids?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman can you please also help me with another one thing - now i need to output all event information from Event model, where `event_id` from that additional table is equal to some variable `foo`

Comment: You're thinking about these things the wrong way; don't worry about "additional tables", try to formulate your problem in terms of the Django classes you have. But if you can't solve this, please ask a new question.